# validate grails domain classes against a database

Tags: testing, grails, integration-testing, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

What's the best way to validate that the grails domain classes are in sync with a database? It's legacy database and i can't build it from the domain classes. An interesting idea [here](http://davidadawson.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/automated-testing-of-grails-domain-mapping-against-a-legacy-db/) which implies fetching one row of each of the domains. However, it doesn't feel like a complete solution mainly because the test database against which I validate may not be so data rich as to have data in all tables.

Thanks in advance for taking time to read/reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a nice approach and must work even for empty tables - if a table is empty, you have no legacy data to worry about validating, right? Or, if you want to test Grails constraints for compatibility with DB constraints, create a new instance of the class and try to `save()` it in transaction - and always roll the transaction back.

If the database is small, I'd even go and remove `max:1` from `list()` - to validate *every* record, because only some of the records may violate constraints.

I'd also replace `println "${it}"` with `assert it.validate()`.

One last optimization, I'd limit the classes tested only to those that I know can violate some constraints. This will save a good part of such a test - and the test is going to take a plenty of time, you know - reading all the database with GORM overhead.

Comment: save n' rollback approach sounds good at first but it's not generic since I'd have to write code to save each domain and its associations. Isn't it? That would mean I'd have to modify the validation code each time the model changes/grows.

Comment: You can generate some random garbage for each field - you can enumerate class' `properties` or `constrainedProperties`.